# Debian : cannot install update : "The transaction did not complete"

Tags: debian, upgrade, software-updates

I have an error message that is popping up every time I boot my Debian 8.10. It says (sorry if mistakes, I'm translating from French) :

> Failed to update.
>   The offline update has failed in an unexpected
>   way.
>   The detail of errors gave by the package manager is :
>   **The transaction did not complete**

Do you have any idea of what can I do to solve the problem ?
What information can I give you about my system ?

When I enter:

```
sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'err|warn|critical'
```

This is what I get:

```
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ0 used by override.  
[    0.000000] ACPI: IRQ9 used by override.   
[    0.187751] ACPI : EC: interrupt blocked  
[    2.432233] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    3.347328] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)  
[    3.347393] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 *10 11 12 14 15)  
[    3.347456] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)  
[    3.347519] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKD] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)  
[    3.347582] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKE] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)  
[    3.347644] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKF] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)  
[    3.347707] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKG] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)  
[    3.347769] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKH] (IRQs 3 4 5 6 10 *11 12 14 15)  
[    3.348133] ACPI : EC: interrupt unblocked  
[    3.770747] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: Signaling PME through PCIe PME interrupt  
[    3.770748] pci 0000:01:00.0: Signaling PME through PCIe PME interrupt  
[    3.770762] pcieport 0000:00:1c.3: Signaling PME through PCIe PME interrupt  
[    3.770763] pci 0000:02:00.0: Signaling PME through PCIe PME interrupt  
[    4.202806] tpm tpm0: A TPM error (7) occurred attempting to read a pcr value
[    4.254888] tpm tpm0: A TPM error (7) occurred attempting to read a pcr value  
[    4.350542] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.4: SMBus using PCI interrupt  
[    4.367200] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode  
[    9.767447] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro  
[   10.672697] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: AER: Corrected error received: id=00e0  
[   10.672713] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: PCIe Bus Error: severity=Corrected, type=Physical Layer, id=00e0(Receiver ID)  
[   10.672820] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:   device [8086:9d11] error status/mask=00000001/00002000  
[   10.672920] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0:    [ 0] Receiver Error         (First)  
[   10.961558] i915 0000:00:02.0: Direct firmware load for i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin failed with error -2  
[   11.178144] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-26.ucode failed with error -2  
[   11.178156] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-25.ucode failed with error -2  
[   11.178165] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-24.ucode failed with error -2  
[   11.179084] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-23.ucode failed with error -2  
[   11.463464] ACPI Error: Needed [Buffer/String/Package], found [Integer] ffff913366b795a0 (20160831/exresop-594)  
[   11.463498] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed  [\_SB.WMIV.WVPO] (Node ffff91336c9b23e8), AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20160831/psparse-543)  
[   11.463526] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WMIV.WMPV] (Node ffff91336c9b2528), AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20160831/psparse-543)  
[   11.465393] ACPI Error: Needed [Buffer/String/Package], found [Integer] ffff913366b79a20 (20160831/exresop-594)  
[   11.465434] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WMIV.WVPO] (Node ffff91336c9b23e8), AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20160831/psparse-543)  
[   11.465461] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WMIV.WMPV] (Node ffff91336c9b2528), AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20160831/psparse-543)  
[   11.467995] ACPI Error: Needed [Buffer/String/Package], found [Integer] ffff913366b79b40 (20160831/exresop-594)  
[   11.468066] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WMIV.WVPO] (Node ffff91336c9b23e8), AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20160831/psparse-543)  
[   11.468111] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WMIV.WMPV] (Node ffff91336c9b2528), AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20160831/psparse-543)  
[   11.474724] ACPI Error: Attempt to CreateField of length zero (20160831/dsopcode-168)  
[   11.474750] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WMIV.WVPI] (Node ffff91336c9b2c30), AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE (20160831/psparse-543)  
[   11.474786] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WMIV.WMPV] (Node ffff91336c9b2528), AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE (20160831/psparse-543)
```

Now when I enter:

```
sudo cat /var/log/kern.log | egrep -i 'failed'
```

It returns me:

```
May 17 10:04:41 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.055881] i915 0000:00:02.0: firmware: failed to load i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin (-2)  
May 17 10:04:41 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.055901] i915 0000:00:02.0: Direct firmware load for i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin failed with error -2  
May 17 10:04:41 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.055910] i915 0000:00:02.0: Failed to load DMC firmware [https://01.org/linuxgraphics/intel-linux-graphics-firmwares], disabling runtime power management.  
May 17 10:04:41 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.408558] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8000C-26.ucode (-2)  
May 17 10:04:41 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.408571] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-26.ucode failed with error -2  
May 17 10:04:41 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.408596] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8000C-25.ucode (-2)  
May 17 10:04:41 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.408604] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-25.ucode failed with error -2  
May 17 10:04:41 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.408625] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8000C-24.ucode (-2)  
May 17 10:04:41 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.408632] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-24.ucode failed with error -2  
May 17 10:04:41 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.421354] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8000C-23.ucode (-2)  
May 17 10:04:41 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.421368] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-23.ucode failed with error -2  
May 17 10:04:41 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.700057] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WMIV.WVPO] (Node ffff9921ac9b26e0), AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20160831/psparse-543)  
May 17 10:04:41 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.700085] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WMIV.WMPV] (Node ffff9921ac9b20c8), AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20160831/psparse-543)  
May 17 10:04:41 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.702515] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WMIV.WVPO] (Node ffff9921ac9b26e0), AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20160831/psparse-543)  
May 17 10:04:41 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.702545] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WMIV.WMPV] (Node ffff9921ac9b20c8), AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20160831/psparse-543)  
May 17 10:04:41 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.704548] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WMIV.WVPO] (Node ffff9921ac9b26e0), AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20160831/psparse-543)  
May 17 10:04:41 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.704576] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WMIV.WMPV] (Node ffff9921ac9b20c8), AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20160831/psparse-543)  
May 17 10:04:41 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.711272] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WMIV.WVPI] (Node ffff9921ac9b2dc0), AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE (20160831/psparse-543)  
May 17 10:04:41 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.711308] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WMIV.WMPV] (Node ffff9921ac9b20c8), AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE (20160831/psparse-543)  
May 17 10:04:41 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.933636] thermal thermal_zone7: failed to read out thermal zone (-5)  
May 17 10:17:55 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   10.961549] i915 0000:00:02.0: firmware: failed to load i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin (-2)  
May 17 10:17:55 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   10.961558] i915 0000:00:02.0: Direct firmware load for i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin failed with error -2  
May 17 10:17:55 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   10.961562] i915 0000:00:02.0: Failed to load DMC firmware [https://01.org/linuxgraphics/intel-linux-graphics-firmwares], disabling runtime power management.  
May 17 10:17:55 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.178138] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8000C-26.ucode (-2)  
May 17 10:17:55 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.178144] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-26.ucode failed with error -2  
May 17 10:17:55 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.178153] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8000C-25.ucode (-2)  
May 17 10:17:55 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.178156] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-25.ucode failed with error -2  
May 17 10:17:55 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.178163] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8000C-24.ucode (-2)  
May 17 10:17:55 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.178165] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-24.ucode failed with error -2  
May 17 10:17:55 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.179079] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-8000C-23.ucode (-2)  
May 17 10:17:55 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.179084] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-23.ucode failed with error -2  
May 17 10:17:55 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.463498] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WMIV.WVPO] (Node ffff91336c9b23e8), AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20160831/psparse-543)  
May 17 10:17:55 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.463526] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WMIV.WMPV] (Node ffff91336c9b2528), AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20160831/psparse-543)  
May 17 10:17:55 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.465434] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WMIV.WVPO] (Node ffff91336c9b23e8), AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20160831/psparse-543)  
May 17 10:17:55 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.465461] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WMIV.WMPV] (Node ffff91336c9b2528), AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20160831/psparse-543)  
May 17 10:17:55 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.468066] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WMIV.WVPO] (Node ffff91336c9b23e8), AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20160831/psparse-543)  
May 17 10:17:55 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.468111] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WMIV.WMPV] (Node ffff91336c9b2528), AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20160831/psparse-543)  
May 17 10:17:55 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.474750] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WMIV.WVPI] (Node ffff91336c9b2c30), AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE (20160831/psparse-543)  
May 17 10:17:55 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.474786] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_SB.WMIV.WMPV] (Node ffff91336c9b2528), AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE (20160831/psparse-543)  
May 17 10:17:55 ufe-m1-14 kernel: [   11.572861] thermal thermal_zone7: failed to read out thermal zone (-5)
```

**Thank you for your attention !**

---

**EDIT:**
Here is the content of `apt-get update`:
(atteint = reached, reception de = receiving)

```
Atteint http://packages.microsoft.com stable InRelease Ign http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie InRelease  
Réception de : 1 http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [145 kB]  
Atteint http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease Ign http://download.videolan.org InRelease  
Atteint http://download.videolan.org  Release.gpg                                                                                       
Atteint http://download.videolan.org  Release  
Réception de : 2 http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie-backports InRelease [166 kB]  
Atteint http://packages.microsoft.com stable/main amd64 Packages                 
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie Release.gpg                                                                                                   
Atteint http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources                                                                                        
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie Release                                                                                                   
Atteint http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Sources                                                    
Atteint http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free Sources                                                                                
Atteint http://download.videolan.org  Sources                                                                                                                               
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie-updates/main Sources                                                                                                                
Atteint http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                 
Atteint http://download.videolan.org  Packages                                                                                                                              
Atteint http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib amd64 Packages                                                                                                    
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie-updates/contrib Sources                                                                                                             
Atteint http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free amd64 Packages                                                                                                   
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie-updates/non-free Sources                                                                                                            
Ign http://packages.microsoft.com stable/main Translation-fr_FR                                                                                                          
Atteint http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main i386 Packages                                                                                                    
Ign http://packages.microsoft.com stable/main Translation-fr                                                                                                             
Ign http://packages.microsoft.com stable/main Translation-en                                                                                                             
Atteint http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib i386 Packages                                                                     
Réception de : 3 http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex [11,8 kB]                              
Atteint http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free i386 Packages                                                      
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie-updates/contrib amd64 Packages                                                   
Atteint http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Translation-en                                                               
Atteint http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en                                                                        
Réception de : 4 http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie-updates/non-free amd64 Packages/DiffIndex [736 B]                             
Atteint http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/non-free Translation-en                                                                         
Réception de : 5 http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie-updates/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex [11,8 kB]                                                   
Ign http://download.videolan.org  Translation-fr_FR                                   
Ign http://download.videolan.org  Translation-fr                                      
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie-updates/contrib i386 Packages
Ign http://download.videolan.org  Translation-en                                                     
Réception de : 6 http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie-updates/non-free i386 Packages/DiffIndex [736 B]
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie-updates/contrib Translation-en
Réception de : 7 http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie-updates/main Translation-en/DiffIndex [3 688 B]
Réception de : 8 http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie-updates/non-free Translation-en/DiffIndex [736 B]  
Réception de : 9 http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex [27,8 kB]  
Réception de : 10 http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie-backports/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex [27,8 kB]  
Réception de : 11 http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie-backports/main  Translation-en/DiffIndex [27,8 kB]  
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/main Sources  
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/contrib Sources           
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/non-free Sources          
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages  
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/contrib amd64 Packages  
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/non-free amd64 Packages  
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/main i386 Packages  
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/contrib i386 Packages  
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/non-free i386 Packages  
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/contrib Translation-en  
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/main Translation-fr  
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/main Translation-en  
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/non-free Translation-en
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Could you post the output of `apt-get update` as is it?

Comment: Thank you, I updated my post. I also used `dpkg -l | grep -v '^ii'` and then tried to reinstall the packages that were displayed by using `sudo apt-get install --reinstall <packagename>`. Unfortunately, I am not able to reinstall `linux-image-4.9.0-0.bpo.3-amd64` and `linux-image-4.9.0-0.bpo.5-amd64` because the bash tells me that **they have no installation candidate**.

Comment: You can't reinstall the `linux-image-4.9.0-0.bpo.3-amd64` because the ( outdated ) package is upgraded to the latest version : `apt install linux-image-4.9.0-0.bpo.6-amd64` or `apt dist-upgrade` will updated kernel to the latest verion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for the explanations. I did `apt install linux-image-4.9.0-0.bpo.6-amd64` and `apt dist-upgrade`. However, I still have the error message popping up at start every time I boot.

Comment: It is a known firmware bug, update your BIOS